# Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interface

So I have a class `cat` which implements a interface `Vocal`, I was wondering why when I 
created a `ArrayList(Vocal)` I was able to add instances of `cat` to it?

Thank You

Comment: Take a look at covariance as this is what is going on here.

Answer (score 6):

It's because when `Cat` implements `Vocal` it's an IS-A relationship: `Cat` IS-A `Vocal`.

Since the `List<Vocal>` accepts anything that is `Vocal`, adding an instance of `Cat` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will be able to add an instance of any class that is declared to implement `Vocal`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the relationship will be exactly the same

Cats IS A Vocal too.

So that was the reason you are able to add the arraylist of CATS in Vocal Type Arraylist